# Same Array Index to own Array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Hello I have the following scenario:

The following array is to be changed to a two-dimensional array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Name2
            [2] => Name3
            [3] => Name4
            [4] => Name5
            [5] => Name6
            [6] => Name7
            [7] => Name8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Company1
            [1] => Company2
            [2] => Company3
            [3] => Company4
            [4] => Company5
            [5] => Company6
            [6] => Company7
            [7] => Company8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Street1
            [1] => Street2
            [2] => Street3
            [3] => Street4
            [4] => Street5
            [5] => Street6
            [6] => Street7
            [7] => Street8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date1
            [1] => Date2
            [2] => Date3
            [3] => Date4
            [4] => Date5
            [5] => Date6
            [6] => Date7
            [7] => Date8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date_2_1
            [1] => Date_2_2
            [2] => Date_2_3
            [3] => Date_2_4
            [4] => Date_2_5
            [5] => Date_2_6
            [6] => Date_2_7
            [7] => Date_2_8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => place1
            [1] => place2
            [2] => place3
            [3] => place4
            [4] => place5
            [5] => place6
            [6] => place7
            [7] => place8
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => break1
            [1] => break2
            [2] => break3
            [3] => break4
            [4] => break5
            [5] => break6
            [6] => break7
            [7] => break8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => postcode1
            [1] => postcode2
            [2] => postcode3
            [3] => postcode4
            [4] => postcode5
            [5] => postcode6
            [6] => postcode7
            [7] => postcode8
        )

)
```

**How the final array should look like**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name1
            [1] => Company1
            [2] => Street1
            [3] => Date1
            [4] => Date_2_1
            [5] => place1
            [6] => break1
            [7] => postcode1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name2
            [1] => Company2
            [2] => Street2
            [3] => Date2
            [4] => Date_2_2
            [5] => place2
            [6] => break2
            [7] => postcode2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name3
            [1] => Company3
            [2] => Street3
            [3] => Date3
            [4] => Date_2_3
            [5] => place3
            [6] => break3
            [7] => postcode3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name4
            [1] => Company4
            [2] => Street4
            [3] => Date4
            [4] => Date_2_4
            [5] => place4
            [6] => break4
            [7] => postcode4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name5
            [1] => Company5
            [2] => Street5
            [3] => Date5
            [4] => Date_2_5
            [5] => place5
            [6] => break5
            [7] => postcode5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name6
            [1] => Company6
            [2] => Street6
            [3] => Date6
            [4] => Date_2_6
            [5] => place6
            [6] => break6
            [7] => postcode6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name7
            [1] => Company7
            [2] => Street7
            [3] => Date7
            [4] => Date_2_7
            [5] => place7
            [6] => break7
            [7] => postcode7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name8
            [1] => Company8
            [2] => Street8
            [3] => Date8
            [4] => Date_2_8
            [5] => place8
            [6] => break8
            [7] => postcode8
        )

)
```

```
function test($post_employee_nr){
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/module/dienstplan/_config.php';
$employee_query =  $dbh->query("SELECT FT.*,M.*,O.*,E.*,K.* FROM
            finish_time FT
        LEFT JOIN
            m_schicht M ON FT.m_schichtid = M.ID
        LEFT JOIN
            objekte O ON O.ID = M.objid
        LEFT JOIN
            mitarbeiter E ON E.ID = M.mitarbeiterid
        LEFT JOIN
            kunde K ON K.ID = M.kdid where FT.mitarbeiterid=$post_employee_nr")->fetchall();

    foreach ($employee_query as $row) {   
        $employee_ID[] = $row['FT.ID'];
        $customer[] = $row['kundenname'];
        $street[] = $row['straße'];
        $postcode[] = $row['plz'];
        $place[] = $row['ort'];
        $begin[] = $row['b_time'];
        $end[] = $row['e_time'];
        $break[] = $row['pause'];
        

   $output = array($employee_ID, $customer,$street,$postcode,$place,$begin,$end,$break);  
    } 

$html = $output;

  
    $response = $html;
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I hope I could make it obvious enough

**EDIT**

This is my solution:

```
     $result = array();
foreach($employee_query as $employee_query) {


$result[] = array(
    $days[date('l', strtotime($employee_query['b_time']))],
    date("d.m.Y", strtotime($employee_query['b_time'])),        
    $employee_query['kundenname'],
    $employee_query['strasse'],
    $employee_query['plz'].' '.$employee_query['ort'],
    date("H:i", strtotime($employee_query['b_time'])),
    date("H:i", strtotime($employee_query['e_time'])),
    '<i class="fas fa-plus-circle" style="color:green;"></i>'
    );
}
echo json_encode($result);
     exit();
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried so far? Can you provide your code? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Why the value are changing ?

Comment: The array you showed us had three elements on the lowest level each, but in the code you appear to be stuffing _eight_ values into the arrays. Please show example data that actually matches the code, resp. vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it to a 2 layer array just create a variable that holds the first element of the 3 layer array:

somthing like:

```
var array2D = array3D[0];
```

Also this bit of code seems like its not necesarry

```
$html = array($output); 
$response = $html;
echo json_encode($response);
```

unless you need the array to be 3 layers when encoding it to Json. Otherwise just change it to:

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

Hopefully I understood your question and was able to help a little.

**Edit**

The way your foreach loop is currently running you're only creating a new array for each element then adding the same elements to their respective array and finally storing every array inside a new one (1 array with ALL id's, and one with ALL companynames etc...)

to fix it is very simple.

inside your foreach loop the $row variable looks like this:

```
$row => [idvalue, companyvalue, streetvalue etc....]
```

it's already an array containing the current $row's data, now all you need to do is directly add it to your $output array.

You're new foreach loop should look something like this:

```
foreach($employee_query as $row) {
    $output[] = $row; // when using [] after a variable you add to that array
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

if you don't want to use all the data that your query collected you can specify which attributes you want to use like so:

```
$output[] = array($row['FT.ID'], $row['kundenname'], $row['straße'], etc...);
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the answer, I also discovered the error. I would love to mix the arrays as stated above.

Comment: @Maximum Glad to hear it helped, I've updated my answer. If there's anything else you need just let me know.